# How to set the publisher in .Net msi installer

Tags: .net, windows-installer

I created an installer in .NET and when I run that Installer (.msi) on Windows 7, it shows a popup saying "unsecured publisher do you want to continue".

How can I make the publisher secured?

Answer (score 4):

You need a **[Code signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537364(VS.85).aspx) certificate**.

[Comodo](http://www.comodo.com/business-security/digital-certificates/code-signing.php) is the cheapest I've found at around $170/year, [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/code-signing/content-signing-certificates/) is much more expensive starting at $500/year for the same thing.